# Adding fielddata to fixed text in report designer

Tags: reportbuilder

Using the report-designer of Reportbuilder i want to add a long fixed text to my report with one or more included fields inside the text. Of course these fields should be filled with actual data, adjusting the text.

I remember I have done such a thing in the past, but cannot remember how. I thought you could accomplish this with a Text-field and something like `'This is the text and here {fieldname} fielddata is inserted'`, but that doesnt seem to work

Can anybody help?

Using reportbuilder 15.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response from Digital Metaphores:

> Use the RichtText component! By setting MailMerge to true, you can add
>   datafields to text in the richtext editor

This adds the reference to the fielddata as a xml tag. Adding the fields Name from pipeline plData can be done like this:

```
<dbtext datapipeline='plData'>Name</dbtext>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fill in the fixed text, then (making sure the focus is set to the text box, I.E. you have the flashing pipe cursor) right click in the place you want the data field to go, and click Create Placeholder.

In the Placeholder properties window give it a Label so you know what it is, then use the "Value" field to define what data from your datasets you want to be brought through.

You should end up with the Label you set in square brackets, like [Example] within the set text.

Comment: I don't think you are talking about the same Reportbuilder that I mean (i mean the one from Digital Metaphores). My Reportbuilder does not have a Create Placeholder in the text-component